# How to open a pdf file on the server without mapping the destination folder?

Tags: vba

I use Shell command to open a pdf file which is physically on the server. The command works fine because I have a destination folder mapped on my computer. What I'm trying to do is to open a file without having a mapped folder.
I find it hard to get my mind around if it's possible at all?

Here's the piece of code I use:

```
Sub open_file()   
VBA.Shell "Explorer.exe \\servername\Documents\2021\2\3\new_document.pdf", vbNormalFocus
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub open_file()   
  Dim wsh
  Set wsh = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
  'if path contains spaces it should be enclosed in quotes
  'error handling required (path doesn't exist, pdf application isn't installed, etc.)
  wsh.Run "\\servername\Documents\2021\2\3\new_document.pdf"
End Sub
```

Comment: It works fine if I have a destination folder mapped, if not it returns an error "Method Run of object IWshShell3 faild"

Comment: `\\servername\sharename\folder\file.ext`.

Comment: Unfortunately it seems to me it won't work until destinaction folder is mapped.

Comment: Can you manually open file by UNC-path "\\servername\Documents\2021\2\3\new_document.pdf" using Explorer window or "Start-Run.."  command without mapping network folder?